# Need to parse protocol-buffer data

Tags: mysql, node.js, protocols, protocol-buffers

I have never used the protocol-buffer, I am getting data in protocol-buffer and need to parse the data and query the data from mySQL database to show in view using Nodejs.

Can any one help me with any links and solution to retrieve data and parse from protocol-buffer.

Comment: You can check here https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs

Comment: MySQL and protocol buffers...are you somehow using the MySQL X Protocol directly? Can you elaborate a bit on that?

In any case, Google also has a JavaScript library to work with protocol buffers - https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-protobuf.